# Terraria purple particles on monster

Tags: terraria

So I was playing Terraria today and during a blood moon a Demon Eye with three rotating bright purple particles appeared. Do these particles mean anything, or are they just some useless random effect? I saw them before on an Antlion Charger.
This is what they look like:

[image: purple particles]
[image: more purple particles]
[image: yay, purple particles again]

So three particle "sources", rotating around the center of the monster.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those particles appear if you have a summoned [minion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Summon_weapons) (such as the Imp or the Hornet) and you have right-clicked on the monster while holding the summoning tool. Three small purple particles will revolve around the monster you clicked, and your minions will try to focus on that target instead of any other nearby enemies. This is useful in boss fights where the boss summons a bunch of smaller monsters (such as the Eye of Cthulhu or the Wall of Flesh), since it increases your DPS against the biggest threat.

This is a new feature in 1.3.4 - prior to this version, minions would simply attack whatever enemies were closest/easiest to reach.

Edit:Further info: While playing around with the summoning items, I did notice that often you don't even have to click directly on a monster - it's quite possible that you had the summoning staff equipped and right-clicked in the general vicinity of the monster. This would still attach those particles if the monster was "close enough" to your cursor when you clicked.

Comment: I had no idea you could do this!

Comment: @JonahBishop Yep, it's a great addition! This simple change really buffed the previously mediocre summoner class. Now if only the thrower class could get some love... or more than one armor set. :P